# Align: Bottom to top

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

I'm wondering if it's possible to position relative container with unknown height at the bottom left of a website so that any text in it starts at the bottom and goes up (as we add it)? It's like exact opposite of how browser usually renders it (from top to bottom, vertically).

Example:

```
<div class="container">Unknown amount of text</div>
.container { max-width: 600px; left: 100px; bottom: 100px; position: absolute; }
```

This works just fine but if `Unknown amount of text` is longer than height of user's monitor, vertical scrollbar does not appear. It requires `position: relative;` then but is there any way to make this container stick to the bottom left with `position: relative;`?

I'm looking for HTML/CSS solution only (if that's possible at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer div to get some manipulation effect.

Give same `bg color` to both `parent and child div` then it give the bottom to top effect.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">Unknown amount of text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{height:100%}
.wrap{ background:green; overflow:auto; height:100%}
.container { max-width: 600px; background:green; position:absolute; bottom:0; }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vdgEK/3/)**

Comment: Thanks but in this example, if text is 5 times longer, vertical scrollbar won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one i think this one help you
just changes in css. & in bottom you just increase margin top for set the bottom align.

```
.container { max-width: 600px; left:0; margin-top:200px; position: relative; }
```

Comment: This doesn't make it positioned at the bottom. It's just standard container with top margin.